# Idiomatic way of returning 2 values

Tags: c++, return-value, c++20, return-value-optimization

What is the *modern* approach when it comes to returning two values (e.g. a `vector` and a `bool`)?

This one:

```
bool tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount,
               std::vector< std::string >& foundTokens )
{
    // fill foundTokens which has been declared in the call site
}
```

or this one:

```
auto tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    std::vector< std::string > foundTokens;

    // fill foundTokens which is a local variable

    bool isValid = true;

    return std::make_pair< bool, std::vector<std::string> >( std::move( isValid ),
                                                             std::move( foundTokens ) );
}
```

or maybe another approach?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you have some modern C++17 answers on the dupe

Comment: @bolov I don't understand.

Comment: There aren't *idiomatic* approaches.  There are *options* that are each suitable in some circumstances and not others.  These options include returning a `std::pair`, returning some other user-defined type that contains the desired pair of values (possibly with additional values), passing one or both values as reference arguments to be filled.

Comment: @digito_evo what is it you are having problems with?

Comment: @bolov I want to know if returning a `pair<bool, vector>` is bad in terms of efficiency or not. How many bytes will be copied in this approach? 24+1? `vector` is 24 bytes on my compiler.

Comment: @digito_evo that's not what your question says. Anyway the answer is there is no copy thanks to the new C++17 temporary materialization rules.

Comment: @bolov So in this case by returning a pair, no copy will be made, right? You mean 0 bytes?

Comment: @digito_evo instead of `pair<bool, vector>` it's better to return `std::optional<vector>`

Comment: @phuclv But then how will it return the bool flag?

Comment: @digito_evo it's wrapped by the `std::optional` class. Read the documentation first and you'll see how it works

Comment: std::optional is suitable, iff the bool specifies, whether the vector is valid

Comment: @phuclv Thank you for the suggestion. Using `std::optional` made my code more readable.